# Fazer cálculos PHP

Tags: php, html, matemática

Estou com algumas dúvida em relação a uns cálculos, eu fiz a seguinte tabela utilizando html e php, o que pretendo agora é que o resultado me calcule percentagens. Ou seja, caso meta for igual a avaliação final o resultado será 100%, por outro lado, se a avaliação final for menor do que a meta deverá dar 0%, porém existe ainda outra situação, Avaliação final = Avaliação Inicial mas inferior à meta deverá aparecer 75%. Espero que consigam entender o que pretendo porém a nível de código não o estou a conseguir fazer, alguém me consegue ajudar?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste o trecho de código que você já fez para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Você pode fazer isso apenas com if encadeado...

Answer (score 0):

Pra calcular porcentagem utilize **regra de três**.

Se quiser saber qual a porcentagem **4** representa de **8**:
`(4 * 100) / 8`